# TFS recursively get specific version of files that were checked-in before a specific date

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control

In TFS, I want to recursively get specific version of files that were checked-in before a specific date. When I specify a date - for those files that were not checked-in exactly at that date (but rather before or after ) I get unexpected versions. Is there a better way to do that? (these files' versions are not labeled and are not contained under the same changeset)

Answer (score 3):

You can get spefiic versions by selecting "Source Control --> Get Specific Version". In the popop that will appear, you will see a "Version" area. Select "Changeset" as Type. After selecting "Changeset" a textbox with a button "..." will appear. Click that button and choose the needed "Create date". That it.

Comment: Or just select "date" instead of changeset for one less layer of abstraction.

Comment: First answer solved my problem, thanks. As for the comment above, selecting "date" was problematic for those files that haven't had new version exactly at the specified date